# Idea behind Zksnark protocols

Tags: zk-snark

It has been for a while that I have been studying and making effort to underestand the zksnark protocols such as groth16 and plonk. However, things didn't well as I expected.

To me, all zksnark protocols assume there is a program such f(x,w)=y, then this programm is converted  to circuit c(x,w)=y.  Both groth16 and plonk make some polynomials from the circuit. Next, Prover construct a proof that I know those polymonials and Verifier can verify the provers's claim.

My question is why we should convert polynomial f(x,w)=y into other polynomials! What is the idea behind this trik?

I review zksnark papers, however, the more I read the more confused I became.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the reasoning behind ZK stuff is quite complicated and not easy to understand. So don't worry, you're not the only one suffering.

Part of the point is that, depending on the ZK system, they can only accept polynomials of certain format. For example R1CS systems can only accept polynomials which are of format `A * B - C = 0` (https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55963/converting-to-rank-one-constraint-system-r1cs?rq=1).

There may be also other factors involved. For example, if I remember right, STARKs utilize a separate reference polynomial, so it doesn't use just one but two polynomials for calculations.